# Using hyphen in the Description file of an R package

Tags: r, ascii, r-package

I am putting some references in the Description file of an R package. One of the authors has a hyphen in the surname, say *Anne-Marie*.

The problem with this is that the pdf produced in `R CMD check` had curtailed the sentence from the hyphen (One sentence ends with *Anne-*, and the next starts with *Marie*).

I tried putting - using Unicode as well (I am using vi, so I `ctrl + v`, and the typed `045` to get `-`). Still no luck.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks

Following is an example `Description` in the DESCRIPTION file

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quis mperdiet aenean t-distribution velit.
>   Vitae nullam lectus-nullam sollicitudin quam imperdiet. Odio commodo
>   commodo eu commodo enim orci ipsum elit id vestibulum eu. see also A
>   Anne-Marie (1984) <1234/5678-91011(12)13-4> B someone, C another
>   (1984) <1234/5678-91011(12)13-4>.1

The PDF output is something like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quis mperdiet aenean t-
distribution velit. Vitae nullam lectus-nullam sollicitudin 
quam imperdiet. Odio commodo commodo eu commodo enim orci 
ipsum elit id vestibulum eu. see also A Anne-
Marie (2019) <1234/5678-91011(12)13-4> B someone, C ano-
ther (1984) <1234/5678-91011(12)13-4>.1
```

Comment: maybe using dash —

Comment: Use initials instead of first names?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck It is a surname.

Comment: Have you tried `\u2010`?

Comment: Do you have `Encoding: UTF-8` in your DESCRIPTION file? I don't know, but perhaps the hyphen is non-ASCII.

Comment: @Roland I gave it a try, but it didn't work. It printed `\{}u2010` in the pdf. I also have put `Encoding: UTF-8` in the DESCRIPTION file too as @Stephane suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour is that I have the whole description in a single line. (I didn't know it is possible to have the Description in multiple lines in the DESCRIPTION file.)

Now, I have broken the Description to multiple lines, and it solves the problem. For this, all lines (except the first) in the Description needs to be indented by **four spaces**.

Once indented this way, the pdf has the same line breaks as in the DESCRIPTION file.